# ProtocolBuffer inside Unity3D targeting iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to use Marc Gravell's [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) `C#` protocol buffer implementation, in a `Unity3D` project targeting `iOS` devices.

I managed to create a `C#` file (let's call it `MyFile.cs`) from a protocol buffer file `MyFile.proto` using `protogen`.

Once imported the file and `protobuf-net.dll` (I'm using the dll inside unity folder), I can successfully deserialize a previously serialized file (I'm doing the serialization from python code and all works fine):

```
MyType myType;
using (var file = File.OpenRead("Assets/MyTypeBin")) 
{
  myType = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<MyType>(file) ;
}
```

The above solution works fine on the simulator, but fails when targeting the `iOS` device (es.ipad).

I tried to switch from the `unity/protobuf-net.dll` to `CoreOnly/ios/protobuf-net.dll` but with the last one it fails to compile.It seems that `Deserialize` method is not declared inside the core dll:

> error CS0117: `ProtoBuf.Serializer' does not contain a definition for`
>   Deserialize'

I've read this [article](http://www.frictionpointstudios.com/blog/2011/3/31/using-protobuf-net-serialization-in-unity-iphone.html), but it seems quite outdated. It refers to an old implementation of `protobuf-net`. I hope something changed in the meanwhile.

My question are:

1. is it possible to use `protobuf-net r602` targeting an `iOS` device from `Unity3D`, without

   > creating a library dll (assembly) of the model classes you want to
   >   serialize/deserialize

   like suggested in the linked blog post? I'd like to have a faster workflow, possibly importing directly `C#` file generated with `protogen` inside a `Unity3D` project
2. If yes, how? which `dll` do I need to reference? Which are the steps to make the above snippet to work again on a `iOS` device?

Comment: What is the error that occurs on the device? Also: for performance, the preferred way *is* to generate a dto assembly and then use "precompile": the lack of meta-programming on iOS is the reason for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: unfortunately I don't have the device with me right now. The error was something about JIT. If I don't go wrong was something like: ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method. So the right way to go is to follow the linked blog article? But it refers to a depracated version of your software: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/detail?name=iDevice%20alpha%201.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution:

> On iOS, there is a problem with Apple does not allow JIT compile on runtime which prevents protobuf usage. It can be solved with Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes"); before any protobuf use, but it works only on .NET 4.6. (I tried on 3.5 and the error about JIT still comes up)

https://github.com/5argon/protobuf-unity